# Geb Testing read all the values inside the div

Tags: groovy, geb

I was trying to read all the content inside the div but it was showing only the few contents.

**Script**

```
$('[class=info] .direction')*.text()
```

**Actual Output**

```
direction[E, E, E, E, , ]
```

**Expected Output**

```
direction[E, E, E, E,E ,E ]
```

Some of the contents are missed. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Are they created by some sort of javascript code?

Comment: Could you create a HTML file to reproduce this problem?

Comment: tim_yates - No sorting at javascript code

Comment: first four child text are able to pull and rest of things are blank